# wxPython StaticText in class not updating

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a simple local network chat program with a chat log that is a `wx.StaticText` object and I'm having issues with it not updating when I set the label. I had it working previously with just `self.chat_box.SetLabel(chatHistory_Display)`, but that was before I had to separate the elements into their own panels so I could have a scrolling panel for just the static text.

When running the program, you type a message in the bottom textctrl box, hit Enter or click the send button, then your message is supposed to appear in the black chat history box. The code runs fine with no errors, and when running the code step by step, the chatHistory and chatHistory_Display variables contains the correct value, but nothing happens when setting the label. The text box remains blank.

My code below. Apologies, I'm sure my code is a mess as I'm very new to wxPython and python in general and I'm trying to learn. The `LogPanel` class below contains my static text object, and the function i'm calling that sets the label is in `append_chat`.

```python
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

chatHistory = []


class LogPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetupScrolling()

        # Chat log
        self.chat_box = wx.StaticText(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.BORDER_THEME | wx.VSCROLL | wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE)
        self.chat_box.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE))
        self.chat_box.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE))

        # Sizer
        sizer_log = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self)
        sizer_log.Add(self.chat_box, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_log)

    def append_chat(self, message):
        chatHistory.append(message)
        print('Message to be added: ' + message)  # Prints message to be appended to chat history
        chatHistory_Display = ''
        for message in chatHistory:
            chatHistory_Display += message + '\n'
        self.chat_box.SetLabel(chatHistory_Display)
        print('Entire chat history: ' + str(chatHistory))  # Prints entire chat history


class SendPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Send button
        self.my_btn = wx.Button(self, label='Send')
        self.my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.send_message)  # Even bind

        # Message box
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER | wx.TE_MULTILINE, parent=self)
        self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.key_code)

        # sizer
        box_send = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box_send.Add(self.my_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        box_send.Add(self.text_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(box_send)

        self.function = LogPanel(self)

    def send_message(self, event):
        msg = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if msg:
            self.function.append_chat(msg)
            self.text_ctrl.Clear()

    def key_code(self, event):
        unicodeKey = event.GetUnicodeKey()
        if event.GetModifiers() == wx.MOD_SHIFT and unicodeKey == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.text_ctrl.WriteText('\n')
            # print("Shift + Enter")
        elif unicodeKey == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.send_message(event)
            # print("Just Enter")
        else:
            event.Skip()
            # print("Any other character")


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Chatting with Bob', name='Local Instant Messenger')

        # Panels
        main_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sub_panel_Log = LogPanel(main_panel)
        sub_panel_Send = SendPanel(main_panel)

        # Sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(sub_panel_Log, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(sub_panel_Send, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        main_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've look everywhere online and couldn't find any answer that worked for me. I've tried all kinds of combinations of `Refresh()` and `Update()` like `self.Refresh()`, `LogPanel.Refresh()`, `MyFrame.Refresh()`, just plain Refresh(), and others I can't remember (Pretty much any combination/placement PyCharm would be satisfied with. I tried `wx.Yield` as well.

I also tried using `wx.TextCtrl` with `wx.TE_READONLY` before splitting things up into separate classes, but I didn't like that it shows the cursor and even with `wx.TE_MULTILINE` the text wouldn't create new lines.

I have no idea what I'm doing, so any guidance would be helpful. Other tips not related to this specific issue would be appreciated as well.

Thanks.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's nigh impossible to run that code, without the right set up, so try simply printing out the message, at each stage, you think you have received a message. Include the chat history just before you update the label. Often, something's gone awry and you haven't spotted it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to shorten it. I updated my post shortening the code as much as I know how. Cut out about 2/3s of the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is that weird glyph attached to your frame.

It's a second occurrence of the `LogPanel` created in `SendPanel` by this line `self.function = LogPanel(self)`.

Again, it's my bete noire, everything sitting in it's own class.

You need to point to it not recreate it and pointing to it, is either by directly creating a variable for the purpose or tracking it down through the hierarchy.

Here's a simple way, by getting it via the grandparent:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

chatHistory = []


class LogPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetupScrolling()

        # Chat log
        self.chat_box = wx.StaticText(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.BORDER_THEME | wx.VSCROLL | wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE)
        self.chat_box.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE))
        self.chat_box.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE))

        # Sizer
        sizer_log = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self)
        sizer_log.Add(self.chat_box, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_log)

    def append_chat(self, message):
        chatHistory.append(message)
        print('Message to be added: ' + message)  # Prints message to be appended to chat history
        chatHistory_Display = ''
        for message in chatHistory:
            chatHistory_Display += message + '\n'
        self.chat_box.SetLabel(chatHistory_Display)
        print('Entire chat history: ' + str(chatHistory))  # Prints entire chat history


class SendPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        gparent = parent.GetParent()

        # Send button
        self.my_btn = wx.Button(self, label='Send')
        self.my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.send_message)  # Even bind

        # Message box
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER | wx.TE_MULTILINE, parent=self)
        self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.key_code)

        # sizer
        box_send = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box_send.Add(self.my_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        box_send.Add(self.text_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(box_send)

        self.function = gparent.sub_panel_Log

    def send_message(self, event):
        msg = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if msg:
            self.function.append_chat(msg)
            self.text_ctrl.Clear()

    def key_code(self, event):
        unicodeKey = event.GetUnicodeKey()
        if event.GetModifiers() == wx.MOD_SHIFT and unicodeKey == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.text_ctrl.WriteText('\n')
            # print("Shift + Enter")
        elif unicodeKey == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.send_message(event)
            # print("Just Enter")
        else:
            event.Skip()
            # print("Any other character")


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Chatting with Bob', name='Local Instant Messenger')

        # Panels
        main_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sub_panel_Log = LogPanel(main_panel)
        self.sub_panel_Send = SendPanel(main_panel)

        # Sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.sub_panel_Log, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(self.sub_panel_Send, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        main_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

It's perhaps worth noting that using a multiline, readonly `wx.TextCtrl` might be better than a `wx.StaticText` for the log.

Then, you can simply `write` the message, rather than reconstruct the entire statictext.

**Edit**
This sort of code seems to be frowned upon these days (I genuinely don't see why for small projects like this) but since you asked:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

chatHistory = []

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Chatting with Bob', name='Local Instant Messenger')

        self.sub_panel_Log = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self)
        self.sub_panel_Log.SetupScrolling()
        self.sub_panel_Send = wx.Panel(self)

        # Chat log
        self.chat_box = wx.StaticText(self.sub_panel_Log, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.BORDER_THEME | wx.VSCROLL)
        self.chat_box.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE))
        self.chat_box.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE))

        # Message box
        self.my_btn = wx.Button(self.sub_panel_Send, label='Send')
        self.my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.send_message)  # Even bind
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.sub_panel_Send, -1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER | wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.key_code)

        # sub_panel_Log Sizer
        sizer_log = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self.sub_panel_Log)
        sizer_log.Add(self.chat_box, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sub_panel_Log.SetSizer(sizer_log)

        # send panel sizer
        box_send = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box_send.Add(self.my_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        box_send.Add(self.text_ctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sub_panel_Send.SetSizer(box_send)

        # main Sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.sub_panel_Log, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(self.sub_panel_Send, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def send_message(self, event):
        msg = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if msg:
            self.append_chat(msg)
            self.text_ctrl.Clear()

    def key_code(self, event):
        unicodeKey = event.GetUnicodeKey()
        if event.GetModifiers() == wx.MOD_SHIFT and unicodeKey == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.text_ctrl.WriteText('\n')
            # print("Shift + Enter")
        elif unicodeKey == wx.WXK_RETURN:
            self.send_message(event)
            # print("Just Enter")
        else:
            event.Skip()
            # print("Any other character")

    def append_chat(self, message):
        chatHistory.append(message)
        chatHistory_Display = ''
        for message in chatHistory:
            chatHistory_Display += message + '\n'
        self.chat_box.SetLabel(chatHistory_Display)
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! Yeah, a `wx.TextCtrl` is probably easier, but I just didn't like the way it showed the cursor like you could edit the text within it, even though its read only. This might be too off topic, but you mentioned you don't like everything being in its own class; how else would you have a scrolling chat log box, but not scroll the whole window? That was the only reason I did separate classes for everything.

Comment: @LoganAC34 See my updated answer. The scrolled panel is already its own class.